# Como fazer strstr() em jquery

Tags: jquery

Existe alguma forma de fazer [strstr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (que existe no php) no jQuery?

Preciso criar uma function?

quero que seja verificado se existe a string exata que estou passando em outra string, por exemplo:

```
if(strstr("abc", "abcdefgh")){
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é necessário jQuery para isso, apenas javascript puro, que já contém a função `indexOf`, exemplo.

```js
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");

if (n > -1) alert('Termo encontrado');
else alert('Termo não encontrado');
```

[Fonte](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

---

<sub>jQuery é uma biblioteca JavaScript cross-browser desenvolvida para simplificar os scripts client side que interagem com o HTML. [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Use `indexOf` do javascript que retorna a posição de uma *string* em outra. Se o retorno de `indexOf` for `-1` quer dizer que a primeira *string* não se encontra dentro da segunda.

### Exemplo

```
if("string que contém".indexOf("string contida") < -1){
  /* O que fazer se não encontrar a string */ 
}
else{
  /* O que fazer se a string for encontrada. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você vai precisar criar uma função.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var chave = /vai/;
     var string = "Como vai Amancio";
     var resultado = string.search(chave);

     if(resultado != -1){
        alert("Encontrado: " + resultado); 
     }
     else{
        alert("Não foi possível encontrar");
     } 
</script>
```

abraço!

Comment: Note que no caso de `search` o argumento esperado é uma expressão regular, não uma string. Para buscar uma string comum dentro da outra (tal como a função correspondente em PHP) o `indexOf` é mais indicado (pois o argumento pra `search` é implicitamente convertido para uma regex - o que significa que caracteres especiais dentro da string são interpretados como tal, não tomados literalmente).

Answer (score 2):

Existe um projeto muito legal chamado [php.js](http://phpjs.org), nele existem implementações em Javascript das principais funções do PHP, incluindo a [strstr()](http://phpjs.org/functions/strstr/), sendo possível informar até mesmo o terceiro parâmetro.

Exemplo de uso:

```
strstr('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'van'); // Retorna 'van Zonneveld'
```